# Rewrite Android Function to start an Activity instead of dsplaying text

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am pretty new to Android Development and Java for that matter.
I am using an external library by a company that produces stamps that can be recognised on a touchscreen.

I get the application to start and display the stamp data, but I would like the application to start a new Activity once the stamp has been entered.

Please find the MainView.Class and StampActivity.Class below:

Mainview

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import com.onetwocm.stamp.service.sdk.StampBaseView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainView extends StampBaseView {
    public MainView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MainView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MainView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void onInitSuccess() {
        StampActivity.setText("onInitSuccess");
    }
    public void onInitError(String code, String message) {
        StampActivity.setText("onInitError - " + code + " " + message);
    }

    public void onStampSuccess(String stampResult) {
        StampActivity.setText("onStampSuccess - " + stampResult);
    }

    public void onStampError(String code, String message) {
        StampActivity.setText("onStampError - " + code + " " + message);
    }
}
```

StampActivity.Class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StampActivity extends Activity {
    MainView mainView = null;
    static TextView textView = null;

    public static final int KOREA = 0;
    public static final int TAIWAN = 1;
    public static final int JAPAN = 2;

    public static final int KOREAN = 0;
    public static final int ENGLISH = 1;
    public static final int CHINESE = 2;
    public static final int JAPANESE = 3;
    public static final int SPANISH = 4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_echoss);

        mainView = (MainView)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

       // String APIKEY = "xxxxx";
        String APIKEY = "xxxxxx";       // Write you api key
        int REGION = KOREA;             // KOREA TAIWAN JAPAN
        int LANGUAGE = ENGLISH;         // KOREAN ENGLISH CHINESE JAPANESE SPANISH
        String INDEX = "B";         // Write index value received from 12cm

        // Display Initialization
        DisplayMetrics metric = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metric);
        mainView.init(metric);

        // Library Initialization for Stamp
        mainView.PlatformInit(APIKEY, REGION, LANGUAGE, INDEX);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public static void setText(String text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }
```

In the MainView Class exist the function `onStampSuccess`. Instead of returning text, I would like it to start a new activity.
I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should totally avoid static methods as the current structure makes your app highly susceptible to memory leaks! This can be achieved using `interfaces`. Firstly, in a new class define your interface method as (may add more later):

```
public interface MainViewActivityInterface {
    public void stampSuccess(String text)
}
```

Now, modify your `MainView` to accept the above interface:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import com.onetwocm.stamp.service.sdk.StampBaseView; 

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
public class MainView extends StampBaseView { 
    private MainViewActivityInterface mMainViewActivityInterface

    ...

    // method to accept interface var, need to call from activity
    public void initMainView(MainViewActivityInterface mainViewActivityInterface) {
        mMainViewActivityInterface = mainViewActivityInterface;
    }

    // api success callback
    public void onStampSuccess(String stampResult) {
        // StampActivity.setText("onStampSuccess - " + stampResult);
        mMainViewActivityInterface.stampSuccess(stampResult);
} 

    ...
}
```

Now modify your `StampActivity` as:

```
public class StampActivity extends Activity implements MainViewActivityInterface {

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mainView.init(metric);
        mainView.initMainView(this); // this is where we are passing the current activity as interface
        ...
    } 

    @Override
    public void stampSuccess(String text) {
         // this is where interface callback happens, start new activity here
         // may do something with text here
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. 
I tried implementing it, but it gives me a NULL pointer exception for the line `mMainViewActivityInterface.stampSuccess(stampResult);` even though `stampResult` returns text.
Any way to solve this?

Comment: @Stefan  Ok..have you defined the method `initMainView` in your `MainView` and are you calling `mainView.initMainView(this);`? ...call this before  `mainView.init(metric);`

Comment: You are commended Sir!
Thank you very much. Your answer was perfect I overlooked the `initMainView` definition.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following changes to your `setText()` method:

```
public static void setText(String text) {
    textView.setText(text);
    if(text.startsWith("onStampSuccess"){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: It tells me that `this` cannot be referenced from a static context.
The same with `startActivity`.